# Validation rule in lightning data table for Inline Editing

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can we validate the entered draft values were correct or not before saving of inline datatable editing.
For eg: I have built one inline editing datatable in lightning component on contacts object.Now when i edit the email field, and entered some invalid input it should throw an error like invalid email format.How can we achieve this using draft values inline editing.

Answer (score 3):

The draft values saved in Inline edit are visible in the `draftValues`, on click of the save button you can validate the draft values and populate the `errors` attribute and that will automatically display the message to the user.

```
<lightning:datatable
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            data="{! v.data }"
            keyField="id"
            errors="{! v.errors }"
            draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
            onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }"
        />
```

JS Save method:

```
handleSaveEdition  : function(component , event ,helper){


    let editedValues = cmp.get(`v.draftValues`);
    //Run your validate logic on edited values

    //if error display error on appropriate row

    cmp.set('v.errors', {
                rows: {
                    b: {
                        title: 'We found 2 errors.',
                        messages: [
                            'Enter a valid amount.',
                            'Verify the email address and try again.'
                        ],
                        fieldNames: ['amount', 'contact']
                    }
                },
                table: {
                    title: 'Your entry cannot be saved. Fix the errors and try again.',
                    messages: [
                        'Row 2 amount must be number',
                        'Row 2 email is invalid'
                    ]
                }
            });

}
```

[image]

Src: [Lightning Datatable - Errors Attribute](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239718/lightning-datatable-errors-attribute/239720#239720)

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableInlineEdit

Comment: I am unable to access the saved draft values.I tried the following way.   var passvalues =  component.get("v.saveDraftValues");  here i am getting the values which are saved in draft values.after stringifying the below result i am getting [{"field__c":"someid","Id":"someid"}].From here i am unable to access field__c value.how to access this value.