# Displaying multiple errors in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-datatable

As per below salesforce documentation we can display error for lightning datatable by setting the "error" attribute.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation

```
triggerError: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.errors', {
        rows: {
            b: {
                title: 'We found 2 errors.',
                messages: [
                    'Enter a valid amount.',
                    'Verify the email address and try again.'
                ],
                fieldNames: ['amount', 'contact']
            }
        },
        table: {
            title: 'Your entry cannot be saved. Fix the errors and try again.',
            messages: [
                'Row 2 amount must be number',
                'Row 2 email is invalid'
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

the above example is for showing one error. Since `lightning:datatable` has multi-edit functionality, a user can try to edit multiple rows at the same time.

is there any way to display the error for all the edited rows?

I tried to do something like below, but I am getting compilation error.

```
component.set('v.errors', {
                rows: [{
                    a: {
                        title: 'We found 2 errors.',
                        messages: [
                            'Enter a valid amount.',
                            'Verify the email address and try again.'
                        ],
                        fieldNames: ['estDebt', 'responsibility']
                    }
                },
                table: {
                    title: 'Your entry cannot be saved. Fix the errors and try again.',
                    messages: [
                        'Row 2 amount must be number',
                        'Row 2 email is invalid'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    b: {
                        title: 'We found 2 errors.',
                        messages: [
                            'Enter a valid amount.',
                            'Verify the email address and try again.'
                        ],
                        fieldNames: ['estDebt', 'responsibility']
                    }
                },
                table: {
                    title: 'Your entry cannot be saved. Fix the errors and try again.',
                messages: [
                    'Row 2 amount must be number',
                    'Row 2 email is invalid'
                ]
            }]
        });
```

Comment: You can refer my demo here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239718/lightning-datatable-errors-attribute/239720

Comment: @PranayJaiswal : It is helpful, but it seems your example is only handling one error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is messed up. There should be two top-level objects, `rows` and `table`. The `rows` key should contain keys that match the `keyField` values for the table. Table messages themselves should be in the `table` key.

```
{ rows: 
  { a: { title: "...", messages: [...], fieldNames: [...] }, 
    b: { title: "...", messages: [...], fieldNames: [...] }
  },
  table: { title: "...", messages: [...] }
}
```

---

Assuming you had a list of errors from the server, you might do something like this:

```
var errors = { rows: {}, table: {} }
errorsFromServer.forEach(
  error => errors.rows[error.Id] = { title: "...", messages: [...], fieldNames: [...] }
);
errors.table.title = "We found "+errorsFromServer.length+" error(s). ...";
errors.table.messages = [...];
cmp.set("v.errors", errors);
```

Comment: Thanks! it is helpful.
By any chance can we use them with `for loop`? 

I can store the `error attributes` in `List/Map` in the controller, but I want to iterate the error attributes with `for` loop instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: @SFDCGeek Updated answer based on your comment. Does this help?

Comment: interestingly, I did the exact same thing mentioned in the docs, but still not able to show the error messages.  triggerError(event) {
        this.errors = {
             rows: {
                 a: {
                     title: '..',
                     messages: [
                         '...'
                     ],
                     fieldNames: ['..']
                 }
             },
             table: {
                 title: '...',
                 messages: [
                     '..'
                 ]
             }
         };
     }